# Defining distribution function and calculating probabilty of a specific event

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

So i have a random vector $(X,Y)$ with probabilty density:

$$ p(x,y) =
  \begin{cases}
      e^{-x+y}   & \quad \text{if } x>0 \text{ and } y<0\\
     0 & \quad \text{othervise}
  \end{cases}
$$
So I have to define disstribution function of bigger of the roots of this equation:

$$t^2+Xt+Y$$ where $X,Y$ are random variables from the vector.

So the bigger of the roots is:

$$t=\frac{-X+\sqrt{X^2-4Y}}{2}$$

And now i don't know how to define the distribution function of this root.

Also i have to calculate the probability that both of the roots are lower than 1.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't know if it's applicable in this case, but you can sometimes use the CDF method to find the PDF of a function of random variables for which you already know the PDF.

Comment: @TonyS.F. I am having problems just finding a way to do anything with this variable that i got from the equation, since it seems hard to turn into something, and yea i would use that probably, but don't now how to apply to this.

Answer (score 1):

Since $Y$ must be less than zero, we know that the bigger root $t^+$ must be greater than zero. So we are looking for the probability that $0< t^+ \leq 1$. We know that $t^+=1$ when $Y = -X-1$ and $t^+ = 0$ when $Y = 0$. So
\begin{align}
P(0<t^+\leq 1) &= P(-X-1 \leq Y < 0) \\
&= \int_0^\infty\int_{-x-1}^0e^{y-x}\;dy\;dx \\
&=\int_0^\infty e^{-x} - e^{-2x-1}\;dx \\
&= 1 - \frac{1}{2}e^{-1}
\end{align}
In general, $t^+\leq a$ for $a>0$ requires $Y \geq - aX-a^2$. So 
\begin{align}
P(t^+\leq a) &=P(-aX-a^2 \leq Y < 0) \\
&= \int_0^\infty \int_{-ax-a^2}^0 e^{y-x}\;dy \;dx\\
&=\int_0^\infty e^{-x}-e^{-(a+1)x-a^2}\;dx \\
&= 1 - \frac{e^{-a^2}}{a+1}
\end{align}